# How do I configure Maven 3 to use preemptive authorization?

Tags: java, maven, authorization, maven-plugin, maven-3

I've tried a number of ways to get this to work, but I've yet to be successful.  Here's what I've found so far.  Note that I've tried these settings using Maven v3.0.3 as well as v2.2.1.

- [Wagon Providers](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-wagon-providers.html) just seems out of date for Maven 3. Specifying `<wagonProvider>httpclient</wagonProvider>` still gives me the LightweightHttpWagon.
- [HTTP Settings Guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html) again seems out of date.  There's a section on preemptive authorization, yet that doesn't work.
- I've also found [MNG-4792](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4792) which indicates that it's flat out broken.

Has anyone actually gotten this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Preemptive authorisation is generally considered a bad practice. Credentials should only be supplied when a challenge is received. AFAIK the functionality for preemptive authorisation was removed from the latest version of Apache HttpClient (4.x) as it is considered a security risk.

I know, this is not much of an answer. But I hope it clears things up a bit on why it might be difficult to find information of the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use wagon-http with maven 3.0.3, you need to add wagon-http build extension, i.e.:

```
<extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
    </extension>            
</extensions>
```

Note, you need to use exactly 1.0-beta-7 version as there is incompatibility with newer version of wagon.

This also works with 3.0.4.